# Applying group specific functions to a Julia dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia

I would like to apply one of two possible functions to a column of a `DataFrame`, based on its category (one for each function) which is specified in another column.

The use case I have for this is converting the JD times of a list of observations from two separate locations to BJD (Barycentric Julian Date), which is dependent on that location.

For example, if I had a table like:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(:t => 1:5, :location => rand(["locA", "locB"], 5))
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ t      location 
     │ Int64  String   
─────┼─────────────────
   1 │     1  locB
   2 │     2  locA
   3 │     3  locA
   4 │     4  locB
   5 │     5  locA
```

where the BJD time at `locA` = t^2 and the time at `locB` = -t^2 (just for clarity), how could I add this new column?

One way I have tried is to just apply a ternary function:

```
julia> loc_to_BJD(t, loc) = loc == "locA" ? t^2 : -t^2
loc_to_BJD (generic function with 1 method)

julia> df.loc_to_BJD = loc_to_BJD.(df.t, df.location); df
5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ t      location  loc_to_BJD 
     │ Int64  String    Int64      
─────┼─────────────────────────────
   1 │     1  locB              -1
   2 │     2  locA               4
   3 │     3  locA               9
   4 │     4  locB             -16
   5 │     5  locA              25
```

but running a check on the category each time like this seems awfully inefficient (unless the compiler is doing something clever behind the scenes?)

Would using groups make more sense in this case? I run into the problem of trying to add a column to a `SubDataFrame` when trying this though, so I do not think that I am approaching this from the right direction.

Comment: Soon we will add an option to add columns to `SubDataFrame`, see https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/pull/2794.

Comment: Oh wow, this is really recent. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think this would be inefficient, as it seems to me that someone's gotta go and check on those `location`s to see if they're A or not, but IANACS. A quick benchmark on three ways of doing this that came to mind:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools, DataFrames

julia> function add1(d)
           loc_to_BJD(t, loc) = loc == "locA" ? t^2 : -t^2
           d[!, "loc_to_BJD"] = loc_to_BJD.(d.t, d.location)
           return d
       end
add1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function add2(d)
           d[!, "loc_to_BJD"] = ifelse.(d.location .== "locA", d.t .^ 2, (-1) .* d.t .^ 2)
       end
add2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function add3(d)
           transform!(d, [:t, :location] => ByRow((t, l) -> t == "locA" ? t^2 : -t^2) => :loc_to_BJD)
       end
add3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime add1($df);
  10.627 ms (6 allocations: 7.63 MiB)

julia> @btime add2($df);
  11.291 ms (19 allocations: 7.63 MiB)

julia> @btime add3($df);
  1.965 ms (163 allocations: 7.64 MiB)
```

I was surprised to see `transform!` doing so much better here than the simple `ifelse`/ternary operator versions, I feel like I've done something wrong in the benchmark but can't see what it is. Maybe check whether you find the same in your real world use case, but I'm sure Bogumil will be along shortly to explain what's going on :)

EDIT: With thanks to Bogumil's comment below, here's the correct `add3`:

```
julia> function add3(d)
           transform!(d, [:t, :location] => ByRow((t, l) -> l == "locA" ? t^2 : -t^2) => :loc_to_BJD)
       end
add3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime add3($df);
  11.177 ms (163 allocations: 7.64 MiB)
```

So no mystery after all!

Comment: It is easy to explain the difference. Just use `l == "locA"` in `add3` (you have a typo :)).

Comment: In this case `groupby` wiil be inefficient as your `location` column is `Vector{String}`.

Comment: Wow, you are a superhero Bogumił! Thanks for the note about `groupby`

Comment: Thanks, Nils! That's a good point about eventually having to check each location anyway. I guess my thinking was that doing something like `groupby(df, :location)` would be a "fast" way of doing the checks, and then I could operate on the subframes individually, but that probably would not scale too well in the end, especially if I had many different locations to keep track of